# Nested DataRepeaters for C# WinForms and Drag&Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, datarepeater

I am using nested DataRepeaters (v12) in a Windows Forms Application. I want to
be able to Drag&Drop Items from outside the DataRepeater to a DataRepeater
contained inside the DataRepeater. But the Drag-Events seem only to fire for
the top-level DataRepeater.
How can I fix this?

Or do I have to use another control instead of the DataRepeater?

Which one will be the best choice?

Comment: Can you show your current implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got it working. Looks like the problem was  that i hooked up
mouse event handlers to all controls below the top level data repeater,
meaning also the nested repeaters.

After removing the handlers on the nested repeaters and the items below, it works...